# Plotting p-values with ggpubr in grouped plot results in error

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, p-value, ggpubr

I am plotting a `grouped dotplot` with [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2), which works fine. But if I am using `stat_compare_means` from the `ggpubr` package to add [p-value](/questions/tagged/p-value)s, it won´t work. When I am using `compare_means` outside of the plotting environment it works fine and I get the correct `p-values` with the dataset (using `compare_means(X1 ~ X5, data=titer_lung, method="t.test"`).

I am using the following data:

```
> titer_lung
         X1  X2               X3    X4     X5
1  4.531479  NK       mutIRFE_FB Lunge group1
2  4.068186  NK       mutIRFE_FB Lunge group1
3  4.071882  NK       mutIRFE_FB Lunge group1
4  4.117271  NK       mutIRFE_FB Lunge group1
5  4.117271  NK       mutIRFE_FB Lunge group1
6  4.462398 -NK       mutIRFE_FB Lunge group2
7  4.643453 -NK       mutIRFE_FB Lunge group2
8  4.556303 -NK       mutIRFE_FB Lunge group2
9  4.724276 -NK       mutIRFE_FB Lunge group2
10 4.491362 -NK       mutIRFE_FB Lunge group2
11 3.903090  NK    mutIRFErev_FB Lunge group3
12 4.342423  NK    mutIRFErev_FB Lunge group3
13 4.113943  NK    mutIRFErev_FB Lunge group3
14 4.653213  NK    mutIRFErev_FB Lunge group3
15 4.230449  NK    mutIRFErev_FB Lunge group3
16 4.556303 -NK    mutIRFErev_FB Lunge group4
17 4.462398 -NK    mutIRFErev_FB Lunge group4
18 4.230449 -NK    mutIRFErev_FB Lunge group4
19       NA -NK    mutIRFErev_FB Lunge group4
20 4.591065 -NK    mutIRFErev_FB Lunge group4
21 4.230449  NK    d3IDE mutIRFE Lunge group5
22 4.531479  NK    d3IDE mutIRFE Lunge group5
23 4.812913  NK    d3IDE mutIRFE Lunge group5
24 4.544068  NK    d3IDE mutIRFE Lunge group5
25 4.342423  NK    d3IDE mutIRFE Lunge group5
26 4.380211 -NK    d3IDE mutIRFE Lunge group6
27 4.698970 -NK    d3IDE mutIRFE Lunge group6
28 4.716003 -NK    d3IDE mutIRFE Lunge group6
29 4.477121 -NK    d3IDE mutIRFE Lunge group6
30 4.740363 -NK    d3IDE mutIRFE Lunge group6
31 4.255273  NK d3IDE mutIRFErev Lunge group7
32 4.322219  NK d3IDE mutIRFErev Lunge group7
33 4.113943  NK d3IDE mutIRFErev Lunge group7
34 4.176091  NK d3IDE mutIRFErev Lunge group7
35 4.518514  NK d3IDE mutIRFErev Lunge group7
36 4.724276 -NK d3IDE mutIRFErev Lunge group8
37 4.462398 -NK d3IDE mutIRFErev Lunge group8
38 4.785330 -NK d3IDE mutIRFErev Lunge group8
39 4.431364 -NK d3IDE mutIRFErev Lunge group8
40 4.826075 -NK d3IDE mutIRFErev Lunge group8
```

And by using the following code I get the plot I am looking for:

```
titer_plot <- ggplot(titer_lung, aes(y=titer_lung$X1, x=titer_lung$X3, 
                                    fill=titer_lung$X2)) +
  geom_dotplot(aes(fill = titer_lung$X2, color = titer_lung$X2),
               trim = FALSE,
               binaxis='y', stackdir='center', dotsize = 0.8,
               position = position_dodge(0.8)
  )+
  stat_summary(fun.y = median, fun.ymin = median, fun.ymax = median,
               geom = "crossbar", width = 0.5, position = position_dodge(0.8)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("black", "white"))+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "black"))+
  xlab("")+
  ylab(expression('Viral titer/organ [log '[10]*']'))+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(text = element_text(size=10),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=10, angle = 90, hjust=1),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=10), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(size=10), legend.text = element_text(size=10),
        legend.title=element_blank())+
titer_plot
```

When I want to compare group1 with group2 and group3 to group4 I write:

```
my_comparisons <- list(c("group1","group2"),c("group3","group4"))
titer_plot + stat_compare_means(comparisons=my_comparisons, label.y=0,
                     method = "t.test")
```

But then I receive the following error:

> Removed 1 rows containing non-finite values (stat_signif).
>   Computation failed in `stat_signif()`: missing value where TRUE/FALSE
>   needed

I guess it should not have a problem with the `NA` values, since `compare_means` also does not bother.

I am very happy with every help, thanks!!!

Comment: Any reason not to remove the incomplete observations from your dataset?

Comment: What was in `titer_plot` before the sample code you provided? What data does `my_comparisons` contain? Could you provide the code in such a way that we can reproduce your error?

Comment: Either remove the missing values or impute them.

Comment: @ira , I guess I could also remove them, but I thought it would not matter. I also tried the code without the NA value, but it resulted in the same error.

Comment: @7hibault , there was nothing in titer_plot before this. Only how I constructed the data.frame `titer_lung`. my_comparisons contains, as I stated, `my_comparisons <- list(c("group1","group2"),c("group3","group4"))`. So it should compare the first 5 entries of titer_lung with the second 5 entries and then entries from 11-15 with 16-20

Comment: Does it have something to do that I want to compare the legend groups with each other and not the groups on the y-axis?

Comment: @Guacamole , I guess you are right, it doesn't know, where to put the bars.comparisons: A list of length-2 vectors. The entries in the vector are either the names of 2 values on the x-axis or the 2 integers that correspond to the index of the groups of interest, to be compared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that is doesn't know, where to put the brackets (x-coordinates)

> comparisons: A list of length-2 vectors. The entries in the vector are either the names of 2 values on the x-axis or the 2 integers that correspond to the index of the groups of interest, to be compared.

```
titer_plot + stat_compare_means(aes(group=X2), method = "t.test",)  #specify the groups specifically
label.y=5
```

[image]

I have no idea how to overcome this, but the underlying `geom_signif` has a "manual" argument. So I guess you could somehow supply the output of `compare_means(X1 ~ X5, data=titer_lung, method="t.test")` to this geom.

You could also consider to have 8 entries on the x-axis

```
ggplot(titer_lung, aes(y=X1, x=paste(X3,X2), fill=X2)) + ...

my_comparisons <- list(c("mutIRFE_FB -NK","mutIRFE_FB NK"),
                   c("mutIRFErev_FB -NK","mutIRFErev_FB NK"),
                   c("d3IDE mutIRFE -NK","d3IDE mutIRFE NK"),
                   c("d3IDE mutIRFErev -NK","d3IDE mutIRFErev NK"))
titer_plot +  stat_compare_means(comparisons=my_comparisons, label.y=5,
                 method = "t.test")
```

[image]

Comment: And it doesn't have to do with the one NA-value

Comment: Thanks a lot, I guess I will use geom_signif !